# MSB3277 in child project

Tags: c#, .net, assembly-resolution

Hello I got MSB3277 warning in child project if I reference parent project with two different dependencies.

ParentProject.csproj have:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="6.0.1">
<PackageReference Include="Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql.Json.Microsoft" Version="6.0.0" />
```

Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design dependency:

- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational (>= 6.0.1)

Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql.Json.Microsoft dependency:

- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore (>= 6.0.0)

ChildProject.csproj have:

```
<ProjectReference Include="ParentProject.csproj" />
```

Assembly resolotion goes fine in Parent project, but in Child I got:

> warning MSB3277: Found conflicts between different versions of
> "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" that could not be resolved.

Is it a bug in dotnet?

Comment: What EF dependencies does the child project have? Guessing it's not EF Core 6

Comment: Basically it is UnitTest project (.net6.0). Thich have some xUnit\FluentValidation dependencies and reference to parent project.

Comment: A test project should use the same versions of packages that the main project uses. Not sure why you'd want EF in a **unit test** project

Comment: Test project just reference parent project, so it is using same versions, I will create an example give me a bit time =)